# Short for "time period in life" like teenage

Tags: single-word-requests, time

I am looking for a word to describe a **time period in life**, like *teenage*, but that would work for any time period, like 11 – 22. I want to say *it is xxxxxx* in everyone's life.

Comment: Age (e.g.it is that age). Suggest: Can you edit your question to be a little more specific? As in can you give reference to context where you are trying to use this word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider "[life stage](http://www.usu.edu/anthro/childhoodconference/reading%20material/life_stages.doc)" or "[stage of life](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=life+stages%2Cstages+of+life&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clife%20stages%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstages%20of%20life%3B%2Cc0)" as common expressions that work for all periods of life.

> stage: a distinct period of development, growth, or progress.

Answer (score 1):

*Seasons of life* to refer to different periods trough which life has changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many specific intra-vitam stages from young to old: adolescence or [the the time period between the beginning of puberty and adulthood](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/2085/adolescence) to presenium or [The period of life preceding old age.](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/739532/presenium)

Answer (score 0):

In some  situations "age group" would fit.